# Python - print image bit data to a ESC/POS printer with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

I've been looking for an example of how to format and print bmp's to my receipt printer (so I can add logos) for a long time, so I doubt this is a duplicate post considering others were for java or other script languages.  Usually I'm pretty good at understanding instructions, but all I seem to find is the same old instructions I can never fully understand.

I am using python 2.7 and I have a function pI(x) which uses win32print to send data to the printer, where x is the data in string format using "\x??" for hex data like formatting text.  It seems to work well.

The programmer manual that came with my printer says (for downloading bit image, GS *) for syntax:

```
Hex   1D 2A x y d1...dk
```

and:

```
d=1 for printing the corresponding dot and d=0 for not printing the corresponding dot.
```

Here is my questions about these instructions:

Does this mean that all x, y, d1...dk is in hex (or "\x??")?  I think so.

What is x and y representing?  I read a while ago on a site (maybe this one) that x+y*255 = image width, and I assume that is using the order of operations.  Is this correct?

The instructions on my generic printer also state that x and y are both supposed to be between 1 and 48, totaling no more than 1500, unlike some manuals which say x is supposed to be between 0 and 3 and y being between 1 and 128 (I think) which said x+y*255=width, totaling about 2000.  it also says k=x*y*8 which I think that the example would be 8*8*8=512*"\x01", so where does the third 8 come from and how do I code that in the string???  Does x=width and y=height?... then how do I get an image width of the maximum 384 dots?

Does this mean that I have to enter "\x00" or "\x01" for each dot, so one instance (a small black block of 8x8) of GS* would be 64*"\x01"?

Do I have to GS * each group of 8 dots tall or line of 8 dots, or will that overwrite the previously programmed data?

I'd like to later include in my program a means of easily creating logos using a tkinter canvas widget and saving it to a text file for future printing using pI(), so I really need to know how to directly 'download' image data to the printer and using a third party module probably won't work since I want to continue using my pI() function.  Yes, it's ambitious and I'm probably doing it the hard way.  But I'm afraid if I start incorporating too much new stuff I'm not familiar with, I'll get too confused.

Basically, what string should I send to pI() to download an image of a solid 8x8-dot black box with a 2x wide white line down the center on the printer?

[Here's an example of what I would like the printer to print so I can see a working code string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7gVa.jpg)

Comment: You appear to have some reasonable-sounding educated guesses as to what you have to do. Have you actually tried printing a bitmap based on your current understanding of the interface?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, it seems to fail to print.  But without python errors, so that's good.  I think my string is formatted wrong, but without a working example, I'm just guessing my way to failure.  :(  I don't think actual .bmp's are formatted properly for what I'm doing here.